# Continuously differentiability of "glued" function

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following surface for $x,t>0$: $$z(x,t)=\begin{cases}\sin(x-2t)&x\geq 2t\\
(t-\frac{x}{2})^{2}&x<2t \end{cases}$$ How to show that surface is not continuously differentiable along the curve $x=2t$? Truly speaking, I have no idea how to start with this example. Thank you. Andrew

Comment: have you tried to differentiate both functions? What is the derivate for $x<2t$ and what is it for $x>2t$? Is this function continuous in $x=2t$?

Comment: Yes, I've computed partial derivatives. For $x<2t$ I have $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{x}{2}-t$, $\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}=2t-x$ and for $x>2t$ I have $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\cos(x-2t)$, $\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}=-2\cos(x-2t)$. The function $z$ is of course continuous for $x=2t$ but I don't know what to do further. Andrew

Comment: Now what happens after choosing $x=2t$. Maybe you should distinguish between to "z"-functions, like $z_1$ for $x>2t$ and $z_2$ for $x<2t$. By the way, have your already examined if the function is differentiable at $x=2t$?

Comment: I suspect that the function $z$ is not differentiable at $x=2t$ but this is a moment when I've stuck. I don't know how to show it. Andrew

Comment: Differentiability is not that important since you shall only show that the function is not continuously differentiable.

Comment: OK, I think I got it. My function is not continuously differentiable because the partial derivatives doesn't exist at $x=2t$, right?

Comment: What dou you mean with "doesn't exist"? If you have shown that, then it's not even differentiable there.

Comment: In 1 Dimension something like this holds: Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable in $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$ and continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Now if $\lim_{x\to 0+}  f'(x)=\lim_{x\to 0-}  f'(x)=c$. Then $f$ is continuosly differentiable on whole $\mathbb{R}$ and $f'(0)=c$

Comment: Thank you, Quickbeam2k1, for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $x=2t$, what is the value of $\frac x2-t$? of $\cos(x-2t)$? Are these equal?